# Escaping delimiter in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, import, copy

I am trying to import data into postgres. Data fields are comma separated, strings may contain commas, in which case those are escaped:

Data structure:

```
create table v (a varchar);
```

Data file:

```
bus
'Gat\,\\e\'way_MQB'
```

Import command (run under Linux from bash)

```
cat data.csv | psql -d database -c "copy v (a) from stdin with delimiter ',' escape '\\' CSV header"
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

I've been fighting and google against this problem for quite a few hours and do not understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
cat data.csv | psql -d database -c "copy v (a) from stdin with delimiter ',' escape '\' quote '''' CSV header"
```

You don't need to escape the escape character when specifying it. QUOTE defaults to double-quote so you need to pass that.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't have problem with single or doble quotes. Data already comes with some escaped commas this way \, so the COPY is not to take it as a separator.  I am using ESCAPE '\' in the command line but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I my case I made it work by removing the CSV parameter and consequently the ESCAPE '\' parameter, since the file was not really a CSV file with doble quotes. The escaping was done without me specifying any escaping parameter. The default is probably the backslash. So, my final command is like this:

```
psql -d mydatabase -c "\COPY myDBtable FROM 'myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' "
```